# Python Multiprocessing: Detecting available threads on multicore processors

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

At risk of adding the the queue of multiprocessing questions, is there a way to detect the number of available threads per CPU similar to the `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`?  I have a `main()` function being asynchronously called from a pool that has one process per core available (default behavior if `processes=None`).

```
items = [2,4,6,8,10]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=args.cores)
results = [pool.apply_async(main, (item,), {threads=1}) for item in items]
```

However, I would like each of the `main()` calls to take advantage of all available threads by setting the `threads` arg explicitly.

Is there a way to do this, or would it be too platform/system specific? Perhaps it could be done with the mysterious `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`, by combining with the threading module, or some other way?

Any direction is appreciated, thanks!